# civicrm theming

Tags: civicampaign, css

I am trying to alter the layout/theme setings of the petition. I am using a petition with a profile. The petition questions are put in a very narrow left hand column and the answers in a wide column on the right. I can't work out where I would put or alter the CSS to make the questions just sit above the questions. I have attached an image. Any help on tracking down the correct file woudl be appreciated!
[image: petition image]

Comment: If possible, Please provide the link of the question - that would be more easy to give you answer -

Answer (score 4):

There is a file `css/civicrm.css` within your CiviCRM codebase, and that's what determines the layout here, but you should not edit that.

Instead, you have two good options for writing CSS that overrides the default CiviCRM CSS:

- **Edit your site's theme.**  Theme CSS will take effect within CiviCRM forms.
- **Create a custom CSS file.**  Put your file somewhere that won't get overwritten upon upgrade, and set the path to it in the "Custom css URL" field at Administer - System Settings - Resource URLs.

Comment: Ok that was very helpful. I placed the following in my theme's main css file

Comment: .crm-container .crm-section .label {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.crm-container.crm-public .content {
    padding-top: 6px;
    margin: 0px;
}

Comment: This put my questions above my answers and aligned both answers and question to the left. I am not a CSS person so others feel free to point out what's wrong but hopefully it will give someone else a chance at altering this too! Thanks